# Does Windows 8 start sabotaging your pc if you don't activate it for an extended period of time?

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

So i installed Windows 8 about 5 months ago but unfortunately I got the product from a scammer who had already used the product key in another product, so i got stuck with an unactivateable version. It was still functional so i decided to live with it, but all of a sudden my computer keeps freezing and randomly resetting, so i am wondering if perhaps it is Windows doing it? Nothing else seems like a viable reason as to why this is happening as all of the hardware is working fine, and i heard a rumor that Windows used to do something similar. Is this at all possible?

Comment: It is more possible that the scammer scammed you twice with a faulty machine than Microsoft *purposely* sabotaging their pride-and-joy system (they wouldn't get anything good from that).

Comment: The software and hardware was bought from different suppliers altogether, so that's why i didn't think it would be the system as the hardware suppliers looked at the system and didn't see anything physically wrong or any patterns in the restarts or freezes

Comment: Well, computer freezes have a too long a list of possible reasons to correctly diagnose. It can be just about anything - CPU/GPU overheating, faulty electronics, defective disks, poorly designed software, malware, you name it. Unless you detail **exactly** what you were doing before the freezes/crashes, we aren't going to give you a good answer. I assume that if something in Windows becomes corrupt then the system can behave awkwardly, but I stand by the fact that Windows *isn't designed* to freeze.

Answer (score 1):

It seems highly unlikely, although of course possible.

However, you should know that if you legitimately acquired the software and have some kind of proof-of-purchase, then if you report this to Microsoft then they will probably sue the seller and give you a new key.

Comment: It seems there have been cases where Microsoft has implemented spyware-like methods if the activation wasn't done in a certain period of time, however they quickly withdrew such methods and apologized but did deny the accusation of it being spyware-like. So i guess this might be possible, but i have found no other evidence of it happening to anyone else, so i guess it is more than likely something else

Answer (score 0):

Well, it certainly is possible. With games for example, some of the more amusing and effective anti-piracy measures disrupt a game's performance rather than just preventing it from being played. This tends to last longer than DRM that just prevents it from working at all as it takes longer to get detected and thus longer to crack.

That said, I doubt this is what's happening - you're most likely experiencing some other issue. Fact of the matter is, sometimes computers crash for inexplicable reasons. This has been pretty much a feature of Windows. As far as I know the only technical consequence of not activating Windows 8 is that some minor features are disabled (e.g. personalization) and Windows constantly reminds you. I have never heard of any version of Windows deliberately crashing just to screw with people.

All that said, you may be using an illegal copy of Windows. I understand you acquired it legitimately, sort of, and that you're not really at fault that you were given an already-used key. Additionally, I'm not a lawyer or anything and frankly I have never read the full license agreement of almost any software I've ever used. I don't know where you live or what your local laws might be. So I really don't know. But I'm just gonna stick in the obligatory, you know, breaking the law is bad and you should probably check up on that.

EDIT: I should add that using software from an unreliable source is itself somewhat risky, as it could have been modified from the start to cause you problems.